# How to prevent deletion of /data/data/<pckg_name> while Uninstalling Apps (ROOTED DEVICE)

Tags: root-access, uninstallation

When I push a command `adb uninstall com.pckg` the **/data/data/com.pckg** is deleted, but I want to preserve the folder w/o using `adb uninstall -k com.pckg` as I need to install another app with same **package name** & **different signature** which conflicts with `-k` cmd.

I tried `mv /data/data/com.package /data/data/com.package1` but **com.package1** got deleted after `adb uninstall` command.

I don't want to copy the folder to a new location because it takes a lot of time.

Comment: After moving/renaming the package I would reboot the device to make sure all file-handles to the old directory are closed (file-handles survive a rename and then point to the new location).

Comment: @Robert I will try that soon and will update here. Btw is there any way to do this without rebooting the device?

Comment: AFAIK there is a daemon (installd?) that handles (de)installations. Restarting this daemon would be sufficient. However I have never heard that Android daemons can be restarted linke regular Linux daemons. May be killing the daemon restarts it?

Answer (score 1):

if you are already rooted why dont you use titanium backup
**Steps :**

1. Install [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en)
2. Launch it and grant root permissions
3. locate to the app and backup it
4. now close titanium backup and uninstall app
5. install the 2nd apk(the one with different signature)
6. launch titanium backup and restore the existing backup but restore **DATA ONLY** not whole app